# Looping over items in array to assign data-id, but only getting last item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, for-loop

### Objective

- Give each of the gifts a `data-id` of 1 all the way up to `gifts.length` (which is 245) that would then help me to pull the corresponding data from the array
- Find a better way to repeat the structure `.gift` structure for all gifts in the array

### Problem

I have an array of 200+ gifts all with a similar structure, **I've been trying to give each gift a unique data-id, but instead I'm getting the last `ID` in the array, which is 245**

I'm also wondering what the best way to repeat this structure without having to use something like handlebars.js, I've tried [multiplyNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), but I'm not sure if the browser support is great vs. `append`

```
    <div class="gift data-id="">
        <img src="" data-original="" class="gift__image lazy">
        <p class="gift__name">tk-name</p>
        <p class="gift__price">tk-price</p>

        <p class=""><span class="gift__description">tk-description</span> <a href="" class="gift__link">tk-url</a></p>

        <div class="gift__share">
            <div class="gift__icons">
                <a href="" class="link--twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--pinterest" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn--buy">Buy on Amazon</button></a>
    </div> <!-- .gift -->
```

### scripts.js

```
// Loop over all of the gifts
for (let i = 0; i < gifts.length; i++) {

    $(".gift").attr("data-id", [i]);

    // Gift information from gifts.js
    let giftName = $(".gift__name").html(gifts[i].Name);
    let giftPrice = $(".gift__price").html(gifts[i].Price).prepend("$");
    let giftDescription = $(".gift__description").html(gifts[i].Description);
    let giftLink = $(".gift__link").html(gifts[i].URL);
}

function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}

const totalGifts = gifts.length
multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.gift'), totalGifts, true);
```

### gifts.js (There are a total of 245 gifts)

```
var gifts = [
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Air plants",
    "Price": 25,
    "Description": "A small glass globe containing air plants, gravel, moss and crystals, comes in various designs and can brighten up your window or desk ($25) at Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street, flowersandweeds.com, which also sells monthly subscription boxes at various price points.",
    "Category": "Gifts for anyone",
    "Type": "Other",
    "URL": "flowersandweeds.com",
    "Destination": "Cherokee Street",
    "Location": "Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street",
    "Latitude": 38.59,
    "Longitude": -90.2369742,
    "Position": "38.5949207, -90.2369742",
    "ImageURL": "-"
  }
];
```

Comment: I have had some strange problems with let. Have you tried just var instead? also $(".gift").attr("data-id", [i]); I think you can remove the [] around the i. instead like this--> $(".gift").attr("data-id", i);

Comment: Maybe `$($(".gift")[i]).attr("data-id", i);`

Comment: @Icewine (".gift").attr("data-id", i) unfortunately produces the same `data-id` over and over

Comment: @vothaison Tried your recommendation, it produces an empty id

Comment: console.log(gifts.length) <-- Did you do this before you start the loop and see what the length is just to make sure you are actually getting the correct length?

Comment: @Icewine Yes, I have. It shows 245.

Comment: in <div class="gift data-id=""> is data-id="" a class?

Comment: @nocturns2 That might be the problem

Comment: @nocturns2 Despite adding in the missing `"` the previous solutions offered are not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you're assigning each id (and replacing it) to all elements with the .gift class every time you go through the loop.
Try assigning it only tho the current gift:

```
var gift = $($(".gift")[i]);
gift.attr("data-id", [i]);
```

Comment: Tried your snippet, it apparently gives every gift a data-id of `0`

Answer (score 0):

*This might not be the way you want to do it, but if I was doing this, I would do it kind of like this:*

```js
var gifts = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "1 Air plants",
  "Price": 400,
  "Description": "A small glass globe containing air plants, gravel, moss and crystals, comes in various designs and can brighten up your window or desk ($25) at Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street, flowersandweeds.com, which also sells monthly subscription boxes at various price points.",
  "Category": "Gifts for anyone",
  "Type": "Other",
  "URL": "flowersandweeds.com",
  "Destination": "Cherokee Street",
  "Location": "Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street",
  "Latitude": 38.59,
  "Longitude": -90.2369742,
  "Position": "38.5949207, -90.2369742",
  "ImageURL": "-"
}, {
  "ID": 2,
  "Name": "2 Dandilions",
  "Price": 12,
  "Description": "Some explaination here.....",
  "Category": "Gifts for anyone",
  "Type": "Other",
  "URL": "flowersandweeds.com",
  "Destination": "Cherokee Street",
  "Location": "Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street",
  "Latitude": 38.59,
  "Longitude": -90.2369742,
  "Position": "38.5949207, -90.2369742",
  "ImageURL": "-"
}, {
  "ID": 3,
  "Name": "3 Air plants",
  "Price": 6662,
  "Description": "A small glass globe containing air plants, gravel, moss and crystals, comes in various designs and can brighten up your window or desk ($25) at Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street, flowersandweeds.com, which also sells monthly subscription boxes at various price points.",
  "Category": "Gifts for anyone",
  "Type": "Other",
  "URL": "flowersandweeds.com",
  "Destination": "Cherokee Street",
  "Location": "Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street",
  "Latitude": 38.59,
  "Longitude": -90.2369742,
  "Position": "38.5949207, -90.2369742",
  "ImageURL": "-"
}, {
  "ID": 4,
  "Name": "4 Air plants",
  "Price": 2325,
  "Description": "A small glass globe containing air plants, gravel, moss and crystals, comes in various designs and can brighten up your window or desk ($25) at Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street, flowersandweeds.com, which also sells monthly subscription boxes at various price points.",
  "Category": "Gifts for anyone",
  "Type": "Other",
  "URL": "flowersandweeds.com",
  "Destination": "Cherokee Street",
  "Location": "Flowers and Weeds, 3201 Cherokee Street",
  "Latitude": 38.59,
  "Longitude": -90.2369742,
  "Position": "38.5949207, -90.2369742",
  "ImageURL": "-"
}];



// Loop over all of the gifts
for (var i = 0; i < gifts.length; i++) {

  // Gift information from gifts.js
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  // This is how I would do it. This way is really easy to set up.
  // ------------------------------------------------------------
  var id = i;
  var giftName = gifts[i].Name;
  var giftPrice = "$" + gifts[i].Price;
  var giftDescription = gifts[i].Description;
  var giftLink = gifts[i].URL;

  var dataBlock = "<div class='gift' data-id='" + i + "'>\
     <img src='' data-original='' class='gift__image lazy'>\
     <p class='gift__name'>" + giftName + "</p>\
     <p class='gift__price'>" + giftPrice + "</p>\
     <p class=''><span class='gift__description'>" + giftDescription + "</span> <a href='' class='gift__link'>" + giftLink + "</a>\
     </p>\
     <div class='gift__share'>\
      <div class='gift__icons'>\
       <a href='#' class='link--twitter' target='_blank'>\
        <i class='fa fa-twitter' aria-hidden='true'></i>\
       </a>\
       <a href='#' class='link--facebook' target='_blank'>\
        <i class='fa fa-facebook' aria-hidden='true'></i>\
       </a>\
       <a href='#' class='link--pinterest' target='_blank'>\
        <i class='fa fa-pinterest-p' aria-hidden='true'></i>\
       </a>\
       <a href='#' target='_blank'>\
        <i class='fa fa-envelope' aria-hidden='true'></i>\
       </a>\
      </div>\
     </div>\
     <a href='#' target='_blank'>\
      <button class='btn btn--buy'>Buy on Amazon</button>\
     </a>\
    </div>";

  // ---------------------------------------------------
  // append to the contents
  // ---------------------------------------------------
  $("#contents").append(dataBlock);
}
```

```css
.gift {
  background: #22252b;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.gift__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: deepskyblue;
}
.gift__icons i {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.gift__icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
}
.gift__icons a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b64737b88c.js"></script>


<div id="contents"></div>
```